# Recovering the private key from a blockchain wallet address

Tags: wallet, blockchain.info, private-key

One of my friends used my wallet to import a funded blockchain wallet to my wallet id. First this wallet is watch-only and I can't spend the bitcoins inside this wallet because I need the private key. Is it possible to recover private key from the address of this imported wallet ?

Comment: If it was possible to recover the private key from just an address, think about the implications that would that have for every wallet out there.  Addresses are public knowledge:  If private keys could be derived, no account would be secure.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I need to recover private key?,](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/84215/i-need-to-recover-private-key)

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to recover private key from the address of this imported wallet ?

No. You don't have the private key(s) for the wallet and you do not have enough information to get them. The Bitcoin isn't yours anyways.