# Watch only Wallet help

Tags: bitcoin-wallet-app, watch-only, blockchain-wallet-app

i need help. I'm totally New with bitcoin. Last time i would buy something and when i pay i've got an sms-code for bitcoins with that i've to make the pay. I send this to a watch only Wallet. But that was wrong.  What i can do to send it to the right wallet.  I've no pc, only my Handy with the blockchain and bitcoin wallet APP.

Comment: So you sent bitcoin to another watch-only address, do you own that address? If not, you can't spend the funds.

Comment: No. It was the Wallet from the support of bitcoin.org

Comment: Yes i know the adress. What i have to do?

Comment: I asked if you own the address, there's a big difference. If you do not own the address, you don't have the corresponding private key to spend it

Answer (score 1):

> **I send this to a watch only Wallet. But that was wrong. What i can do to send it to the right wallet.**

Bitcoin transactions are irreversible. You cannot cancel or reclaim them. Therefore you cannot now redirect those bitcoins to the right wallet.

Watch-only addresses are controlled only by whoever knows the corresponding private-key.

If you know who owns the private-key to the watch-only address, you can ask them to make a new payment to you of the same amount you sent them. You have to rely on their charity.

---

Related?

- [Reg: Watch only Address](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/75883/13866)