# How do I get imported Bitcoin in my blockchain wallet without having to pay more for the private key?

Tags: blockchain

ich habe Geld investiert anscheinend bei Betrügern, dass lief Alles über Facebook Messenger , ich habe ein Blockchain Wallet erstellt und dummerweise Wallet ID und Passwort rausgegeben, als es um die Auszahlung ging wollten Sie immer wieder Geld und dann war das Facebook Profil gelöscht. Vor ca 2 Wochen, wurde da Profil wieder aktiviert und Sie haben mir versprochen ,jetzt den Gewinn auszuzahlen , aber auf einem neuen Wallet und tatsächlich haben Sie Bitcoin auf das Wallet übertragen , aber nur " watch only" also importierte Bitcoin . Sie wollten wieder Geld für den Schlüssel , einmal habe ich gezahlt , danach wollten Sie wieder Geld und das mache ich nicht mehr , ich habe auch kein Geld mehr . Kann ich irgendwie an den privaten Schlüssel rankommen ? Die Betrüger sagen ja es ist mein Profit . Seltsam ist das diese importierte Adresse bekannt ist .
Bitcoin.org wird von der Community unterstützt: 3FkenCiXpSLqD8L79inRNXUgjRoH9sjXa

---

Translation by Google:

I invested money apparently with scammers that ran everything through Facebook Messenger, I created a blockchain wallet and stupidly gave out wallet ID and password, when it came to payout [they] always wanted money and then the Facebook profile was deleted. About 2 weeks ago, the profile was reactivated and [they] promised to pay off the winnings now, but on a new wallet and indeed [they] transferred Bitcoin to the wallet, but only "watch only" imported Bitcoin. They wanted money again for the key, once I paid, then [they] wanted money again and I do not do that anymore, I have no more money. Can I somehow get to the private key? The scammers say yes it's my profit. Strange is that this imported address is known. Bitcoin.org is supported by the community: 3FkenCiXpSLqD8L79inRNXUgjRoH9sjXa

Answer (score 4):

You cannot get the private key. Your money is gone and you will not get it back. Report the crime to your local police.

Google's translation:

> Sie können den privaten Schlüssel nicht abrufen. Dein Geld ist weg und du wirst es nicht zurückbekommen. Melden Sie das Verbrechen Ihrer örtlichen Polizei.

For more information see the answers to [Reg: Watch only Address](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/75883/13866) and the answers to the linked questions there. There are numerous other people who have been cheated in the same way.

Do not use the blockchain wallet you created. Any money you put there will be taken by the criminals who tricked you into giving them access to it. Their access cannot be revoked by blockchain or anyone else.

Comment: Actually, blockchain.info watch-only feature is an open door for criminals against bitcoin beginners. They should enable this feature for specific users.