# but I haven't heard anything from chainabuse or ftc yet, and I was told that CiperBlade is not supported

Tags: money

Last year, I encountered a scam and the recovery company I met after that got my money back. However, in the end, the damages were not reported back. I recently happened to find the address that was in my watch wallet at the time. It looks like there is a lot of money, but is there a way to access it? I recently reported everything, but I haven't heard anything from chainabuse or ftc yet, and I was told that CiperBlade is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to access money in a watch only wallet.

They are often created by scammers as a view of someone else's money which they use to deceive their victim.
All information on the blockchain is public, you can watch other people's money.

You could set up a watch only wallet to watch money in another wallet of your own, but you would remember having done that.

See

- [Reg: Watch only Address](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/75883/13866)
- [How do I recover from a cryptocurrency scam?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/91943/13866)