# How to add Bitcoins to my wallet

Tags: transactions, blockchain, block

I am new at this and I was given a bitcoin from a miner, how do I know what it is worth and how do I put it in my wallet?

Answer (score 1):

> **I was given a bitcoin from a miner,**

Are you sure you havent been tricked by a conman?

See

- [Bitcoin Mining as a Newbie (link wallet to another person's miner)](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/74841/13866)
- [Reg: Watch only Address](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/75883/13866)
- [How can I get a private key for this address](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/74362/13866)
- [Unlocking a Private Key from watch status](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/73541/13866)
- [Recovering the private key from a blockchain wallet address](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/72746/13866)

> **how do I put it in my wallet?**

One fairly good way is

- download a wallet such as ["bitcoin core" from bitcoin.org](https://bitcoin.org/en/wallets/desktop/windows/bitcoincore/). Some [other wallets](https://bitcoin.org/en/choose-your-wallet) are also available. Never accept wallet software that is given or sent to you by someone over the Internet.
- keep the private-key written on paper somewhere very very safe and never give the private key to anyone who asks for it.
- ask the miner to send bitcoins to the **address** of your wallet.
- wait for at least 6 confirmations of the transfer.

> **how do I know what it is worth**

If there is any mention of "testnet", it is worth nothing.

If you do not have the private keys, it is worth nothing to you.

If someone else also has the private keys, they can take the bitcoin and leave you nothing.

If its in a wallet that a miner created for you, its contents are probably worth nothing to you.

Note that "Bitcoin Cash" (BCH) is not Bitcoin (BTC) and may be worth less. The same applies to "Bitcoin Gold", "Bitcoin Diamond" and a huge number of other alternative cryptocurrencys (altcoins). Don't confuse them.

Otherwise you can find the exchange rate from BTC (bitcoin) to USD (or any other currency) using a search engine. For example [google BTC USD exchange rate](https://www.google.com/search?q=BTC+USD+exchange+rate)

> **I am new at this**

Be very very careful. Lots of conmen prey on people who are new to this.